# SQL Join SUM not properly working

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am having a problem producing a result with my query. I wanted to produce SUM of the result of rows from another table which is related to the primary table.

What I failed to output is the sum of payments, and the sum of payables.

- PROBLEM #1 - I cannot produce a correct output of the Payments. The
  query seemed to produce an formula of `numrows * sum_of_payments`
- PROBLEM #2 - I cannot produce an output of the total payables.

I am using Codeigniter 3 and this is my model.

```
function fetch_billing_records($case_id, $patient_id, $status) {

        $this->db->join('cases', 'cases.id = billing.case_id', 'left');
        $this->db->join('patients', 'patients.id = cases.patient_id', 'left');            
        $this->db->join('users', 'users.username = billing.user', 'left');
        $this->db->join('billing_payments', 'billing_payments.billing_id = billing.id', 'left');
        $this->db->join('billing_items', 'billing_items.billing_id = billing.id', 'left');
        $this->db->join('services', 'services.title = billing_items.service', 'left');
        $this->db->select('
            billing.id,
            billing.remarks,
            billing.status,
            billing.created_at,
            billing.updated_at,
            users.name as user,
            users.username,
            cases.id as case_id,
            cases.title as case_title,
            patients.id as patient_id,
            CONCAT(patients.lastname, ", ", patients.fullname) as patient_name,
            SUM(billing_payments.amount) as payments,
            SUM((services.amount - billing_items.discount)*billing_items.qty) as payables
        ');

        if(is_int($case_id)) {
            $this->db->where('billing.case_id', $case_id);           
        }

        if(is_int($patient_id)) {
            $this->db->where('patients.id', $patient_id);
        }

        if(is_int($status)) {
            $this->db->where('billing.status', $status);
        }

        $this->db->group_by('billing.id');
        $this->db->where('billing.is_deleted', 0);

        $query = $this->db->get("billing");

        log_message('error', $this->db->last_query());
        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            return $query->result_array();
        }

        return false;

}
```

I saved the Last Query with the Last Query and Log Helpers, and it seemed that the query for my instance is

```
 SELECT `billing`.`id`, `billing`.`remarks`, `billing`.`status`, `billing`.`created_at`, `billing`.`updated_at`, `users`.`name` as `user`, `users`.`username`, `cases`.`id` as `case_id`, `cases`.`title` as `case_title`, `patients`.`id` as `patient_id`, CONCAT(patients.lastname, ", ", patients.fullname) as patient_name, SUM(billing_payments.amount) as payments, SUM((services.amount - billing_items.discount)*billing_items.qty) as payables
FROM `billing`
LEFT JOIN `cases` ON `cases`.`id` = `billing`.`case_id`
LEFT JOIN `patients` ON `patients`.`id` = `cases`.`patient_id`
LEFT JOIN `users` ON `users`.`username` = `billing`.`user`
LEFT JOIN `billing_payments` ON `billing_payments`.`billing_id` = `billing`.`id`
LEFT JOIN `billing_items` ON `billing_items`.`billing_id` = `billing`.`id`
LEFT JOIN `services` ON `services`.`title` = `billing_items`.`service`
WHERE `billing`.`is_deleted` =0
```

To guide you more with my present problem, this is the schema of the related tables:

[image]

and this is the schema of the entire database.

[image]

Comment: did u put select sum without group by perhaps?

Comment: @martonohalim I did `$this->db->group_by('billing.id');`

Comment: i am not sure with how code igniter works but your group by seems not having enough column to group. it should put all the column except the sum column. Hope it helps.

Comment: @AaronAlfonso try to put `false`  like `$this->db->select("you select part",false);`

Comment: It seemed that there's no problem with the SELECT with codeigniter. The problem is the proper querying of the SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Use group by statement. because mysql aggregate functions work well with group by. if you want billing sum against patient then use following query

```
SELECT 
    `billing`.`id`, 
    `billing`.`remarks`, 
    `billing`.`status`, 
    `billing`.`created_at`, 
    `billing`.`updated_at`, `
    users`.`name` as `user`, 
    `users`.`username`, 
    `cases`.`id` as `case_id`, 
    `cases`.`title` as `case_title`, 
    `patients`.`id` as `patient_id`, 
    CONCAT(patients.lastname, ", ", patients.fullname) as patient_name, 
    SUM(billing_payments.amount) as payments, 
    SUM((services.amount - billing_items.discount)*billing_items.qty) as payables
FROM `billing`
    LEFT JOIN `cases` ON `cases`.`id` = `billing`.`case_id`
    LEFT JOIN `patients` ON `patients`.`id` = `cases`.`patient_id`
    LEFT JOIN `users` ON `users`.`username` = `billing`.`user`
    LEFT JOIN `billing_payments` ON `billing_payments`.`billing_id` = `billing`.`id`
    LEFT JOIN `billing_items` ON `billing_items`.`billing_id` = `billing`.`id`
    LEFT JOIN `services` ON `services`.`title` = `billing_items`.`service`
WHERE `billing`.`is_deleted` =0
GROUP BY patients.id
```

Comment: I did a `$this->db->group_by('billing.id')` as required by my instance.

Comment: but i know there must be need of group by

Comment: Yes indeed. But I tried to execute via command line, but it has the same output. I believe what I need to know is the proper querying of the SQL

Comment: what result do you want  ?